# Comparison not working when the variable is stored in a macro?

Tags: macros, fontsize, conditionals, expansion

I am trying to branch of font size and the following is not working as I would expect:

```
\def\tinyfont{tiny}
\def\scriptfont{scriptsize}
\newcommand{\setfontsize}[1]{%
    \def\currentsize{#1}%
    \ifx\tinyfont\currentsize%
        \tiny%
    \fi%
    \ifx\scriptfont\currentsize%
        \scriptsize%
    \fi%
}
```

When used like this, it will work:

```
{\setfontsize{tiny}Hello!}
```

but when used like this, it will **NOT** work:

```
\newcommand{\myfontsize}{tiny}
{\setfontsize{tiny}Hello!}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How to make it work?
2. Why is not working?
3. What would be the "right" way to write a function that converts a font size as a text ("tiny", "scriptsize", ..., "huge", "Huge") to the right font size command?

**EDIT:**
Reacting to the comments, for 1. and 2., how to make it work keeping the `if` comparisons, for example to handle the case where the text would not be the name of the command as in: `\setfontstyle{bf} => \bfseries`?

Comment: As to question 3, `\newcommand\setfontsize[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}`  And then invoke `\setfontsize{tiny}`.

Comment: In your example of what *doesn't* work, I presume you meant `\newcommand{\myfontsize}{tiny}
{\setfontsize{\myfontsize}Hello!}`.  If you use my code from my above comment, it should answer question #1.

Comment: And how would I do it if the name to be provided was not the same as the name of the command. For example `\setfontstyle{bf} => \bfseries`?

Comment: I would use separate commands like `\newcommand\setfontseries[1]{\csname#1series\endcsname}` and `\newcommand\setfontshape[1]{\csname#1shape\endcsname}`, with invocations like `\setfontseries{bf}` and `\setfontshape{it}`.

Comment: `\edef\currentsize{#1}%`

Comment: why don't you do `\newcommand{\setfontsize}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}`?

Comment: What would be the reason to write `\setfontsize{tiny}` instead of `\tiny`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that you want to say: when I use

```
\newcommand{\tinyfont}{tiny}  % instead \def\tinyfont{tiny}
{\setfontsize{tiny}Hello!}
```

then it doesn't work.

The reason is that LaTeX's `\newcommand` defines the macro `\tinyfont` with `\long` prefix. On the other hand your code includes `\def\currsize{#1}` so the macro `\currsize` isn't defined with `\long` prefix. Two identical macros, first with and second without `\long` are not decided as the same by `\ifx`. You can use `\newcommand*{\tinyfont}{tiny}` or you can declare `\long\def\currsize{#1}` in your code or you can avoid to use `\newcommand` or you can avoid to use LaTeX.